# Remove div so that google can't see it above 768px

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a responsive website built in Joomla.

I am using a slide in/off canvas navigation which appears when you click the burger icon when the page is below 768px.

My issue:
I am being told that Google doesn't like duplicate menu's.
At present the  is hidden with css display:none until the page hits 786px width or below.
But above 768px width, duplicate navigation can be seen in the source of the page as below (even though it has a display:none assigned to it:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">link2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">link3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="page">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">link2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">link3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Using jQuery, is it possible to completely remove  until the browser hits 768px width or below?

Is this do-able and how would it be done?

Comment: maybe go the other direction and use JS to create the element below the break point? It's a little risky in that a <768 device without JS enabled doesn't get a menu, but if you can live with that it might satisfy your client / SEO grand wizard...

Answer (score 0):

jquery

```
if ($('window').width() < 769){
   $('body').prepend('your menu here');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that a duplicate menu is a big deal for SEO. Duplicate content is generally a negative mark if it's being copied from other sources (i.e. data scraping). If you're adamant about it however your best bet I think is to rearrange the menu, not remove and replace.

**Start With**

```
<div id="sidebar">
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="">link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">link3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="page"></div>
```

Then you'll want to use the window width to make your break-points the same way you would with a media query. At your 768px break-point use

```
$("#page").prepend("#menu");
```

This is using JQuery (that's what I'm familiar with), but prepend will completely move one set of content to the first position of another element.

Then of course you'll want to do the opposite for the other way around. Now if you want to trigger this thing when people are changing the width of their windows to mess with your design (or in a more real-world scenario if your break-points happen to land on portrait/landscape widths for a tablet) you can trigger this on window re-size.